# Social Network Analysis

Tags: networks, social-network

all:

I am new to social network analysis, please pardon if this is a simple question.

I am using GEPHI to create a network.

My data is a set of ratings by peers in group settings (sociometric). All peers rated all other peers in the group on a scale from 1-4 that tapped into "liking". Some youth have ADHD, some do not. I would like to use SNA to determine whether kids with ADHD are on the outskirts of the network (less connections) based on less liked.

It seems that the rankings are a weight, but the SNA that I am getting is simply that all kids in a group are connected -- because they all rated each other.

What am I missing here? How can I formulate this model to answer my question better?

Thanks!
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

A simple binary network can be constructed as follows:
ratings: 1 and 2 treated as 0; ratings: 3 and 4 treated as 1

Now you have a directed binary network, which you can model with an Exponential Random Graph Model (ERGM), in which you can specify many terms of interest, such as

1. number of edges: this captures the overall density of the network.
2. number of mutual edges: this captures the tendency of forming mutual edges.
3. nodematch: this captures tendencies of forming edges within group ADHD and group non-ADHD.
4. transitivity (GWESP term): captures the tendency of forming edges because they have common connections.

http://www.statnet.org/ provides the statnet R package

Comment: thank you. this is helpful. 

can you point me in the direction (if it exists) for a statistical test to compare node strength or other statistics across groups - e.g.,to answer if ADHD kids have singificantly less centrality or node stregth than non-adhd?

Comment: @user3722874  How many kids do you have? I guess not many?  I think some t-test can be helpful, for example, compare average rating within the ADHD group and the average rating within the non-ADHD group; compare the average rating of ADHD group towards the non-ADHD group and the average rating of non-ADHD group towards the ADHD group

Comment: @user3722874   In the directed binary network context, if by centrality you mean "popularity" of each node, then in ERGM, you can use terms: "receiver" and "sender", which captures the number of connections each node received and sent